# python converting 0.00000077 to scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am using python requests to convert usd value to btc.

```
    res = requests.get("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value="+str(float(rawUSD)))

res.json() = 7.7e-07

res.text = 0.00000077
```

Getting '0.00000077' in res.text which a `<class:str>` type so converting it again to float gives me this.

`float('0.00000077') = 7.7e-07`

but i want it as 0.00000077 so i can use it in later calculation. i know both 0.00000077 and 7.7e-07 are same and python treats them as float but i am trying to save the end value in db and i cant save it as 7.7e-07.

how can i do so?

Comment: "but i am trying to save the end value in db and i cant save it as 7.7e-07" - that sounds like you're trying to build SQL through string formatting, which is a terrible idea. Use query parameters, and you should have no trouble inserting your number into the database.

Comment: Dont vote down with out explaining. Its least helpful.

Comment: Also, rather than building a URL through string formatting, you should be using a `params` dict. Really, you need to get out of the habit of building strings manually.

Comment: @user2357112 okay so params dict is the way to get non scientific notation? because i did so change my approach `paramData = {'currency':'USD','value':rawUSD}`
        `RR = requests.get(url="https://blockchain.info/tobtc", params=paramData)`

 and now no longer getting scientific notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of python's [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) module.

```
from decimal import Decimal
print("{:.2e}".format(Decimal(res.text)))
```

Comment: this gives me 9.83e-5, scientific notation again. btw thanks for your contribution.